# python multiprocessing pass dict from child process back to parent

Tags: python, variables, queue, multiprocessing

I have a subprocess function (called parseContents) that gets called using the following code:

```
def main():
   p = Process(target=parseContents, args=(event.name,))
   p.start()
   p.join()
```

Utilizing the multiprocessing module and the Queue method, how would I go about passing a variable from parseContents back to main to be used after the p.join() line?

I've read that I would use:

```
  from multiprocessing import Queue
  queue = Queue()
  queue.put( myVar ) #obviously this would be inside parseContents()
  print queue.get( myVar )  #obviously this would be inside main()
```

Do I need to pass the 'queue' variable/instance to my parseContents function after calling it in my main so the child process knows about the queue?

What would be a correct implementation of a multiprocessing queue between parent and child processes as constructed in the `main():` segment above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a Queue in this way you have to instantiate it in `main()` and pass it to `parseContents` as an argument. Once you do that you should be able to use the code you have (in the correct places) to pass the item from the child process to the parent process.

The Python docs warn that you should not attempt to join the child process if the Queue is not empty, so make sure to get all of the items out of the queue before you call `join`. In fact, you should be able to run the code without calling `join` at all because `queue.get` will wait until there is an item in the Queue.

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs about removing or emptying a queue.  How do I do that before calling .join()?

Comment: I just meant that the item that you have to call get enough times to get all of the items out of the queue before you call join.

Comment: oh gotcha! if I only put 1 item into the queue then I only have to get 1 item out.  I understand, thank you

Comment: kinda unrelated - but does p.join() prevent my calling process from running 'asynchronously'? My vision is to split my subprocess from my loop but let my loop continue running while the subprocesses are finishing their task...

Comment: @sadmicrowave Yes, `p.join` makes the calling process wait for the child process. You can still get parallelism by starting all of the child processes, removing all of the items from the queue, and then ending the child process.

Comment: Do I HAVE to call p.join for it to work properly? I mean, what if I wanted the main process to run asynchronously, and not worry about passing variables back and forth?

Comment: It looks like you would not have any problems if you just skip the calls to join. I've just gotten used to C, where you do have to call join.